# Allow world access to directory under 0750 directory

Tags: permissions, directory, apache-httpd

I prefer to keep my `/home/dotancohen/` directory as permissions `0750`. However, I do need Apache to access `/home/dotancohen/someProject/public_html/`. I know that I could configure the home directory as `0755` and all subdirectories other than `~/someproject/` as `___0` but that is a pain. How might I allow Apache to access the `~/someproject/public_html/` directory yet keep the home directory as `0750`?

I tried to symlink `/war/www/someProject` to `/home/dotancohen/someProject/` but in any case Apache fails to get past the `0750` barrier on `/home/dotancohen/`. I suppose that I could add the `www-data` user (Apache) to the `dotancohen` group, but I feel that is giving it too much power.

Alternatively, I could keep the web files in `/var/www/someProject/` but due to other reasons I prefer to keep them under my home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few different options available to you. Here are the ones I can think of; each has its own merits and disadvantages.

- You can set the world execute bit on the parent directories. That way, anyone who knows the full path to a file will be able to access it, but no one else can. This still does leave well-known files up for grabs though unless you protect them with more restrictive permissions (things like ~/.bashrc, ~/.gnupg, ~/.Xauthority and so on may be of interest to an attacker so would need their permissions tightened).
- You may be able to leverage ACLs to do the same thing with more granularity, e.g. only allowing the www-data user or group execute access to the directories, read/execute access to any directory the web server needs to provide a content listing for and read access to files it should serve.
- You could add the www-data user to the dotancohen group and then revoke group permissions on everything except what you want Apache to be able to access. That's probably the easiest approach that opens up as little as possible, but it gets trickier if you are already using group permissions for some other purpose.
- Or, as you say, you could move the publicly-served files out of your home directory entirely. This is definitely the easiest setup to get right in terms of permissions, and it's certainly the choice I would make unless there's some compelling reason not to. Depending on your setup and specific needs, it may even be practical to use 0750 or 0770 permissions on such a public root with appropriate ownership, which would restrict access to only yourself and the web server. Owner yourself, group www-data and permissions 0710 throughout such a directory tree would probably be about as tight as you can go, but means the web server must know the full name of every file it will access under that directory.

As an aside, you may want to consider migrating to FHS-compliant [/srv](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM) rather than /var.

Comment: Thanks. Moving the files out of my home directory will expose the pages' source code, but all the other options are worse!

Comment: @dotancohen Depending on your setup, it might be practical to set the directory under /var/www to be owned by you and group www-data (or the other way around) and run that at 0750 or 0770 as needed. That would minimize the attack surface while still allowing the web server the access it needs.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea. I'll need to adjust how Git sees the directories, but it should be possible. Thank you!