# File is inaccessible to another user even though group permissions on it are granted

Tags: permissions

I created a file `/home/andrew/lolka123` and granted `read` permission to a group named `andrew`. (user **andrew** owns the  file and also a parent directory) I also added group permission to the parent directory.

Now I want to grant access to this file to user **http**.

Both users **andrew** and **http** are present in group `andrew`.
Now I'm trying to read file from **http** user but it gives me `Permission denied`, why?

**getfacl `/home/andrew/lol123`**:

```
# file: home/andrew/lol123
# owner: andrew
# group: andrew
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

getfacl `~/`:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/andrew/
# owner: andrew
# group: andrew
user::rwx
user:nobody:--x
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
```

**EDIT 2**:

`sudo chmod g+rx /home/andrew/` doesn't work.  `getfacl /home/andrew/` still shows `group::---`
[image]

Comment: Show output of `getenforce` please. What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using ArchLinux bleeding edge with `4.11.9-1` kernel. `getenforce` command is not available, and it's not available in any packages from `Arch` repository.

Comment: The '+' at the end of the permission string indicates there are additional ACLs.  What is the output of `getfacl .` ?

Comment: This question is not related to apache,  I included `getfacl .` to the question.

Comment: Check the folder permissions

Comment: @Katu `ls -ldz /home/andrew` shows `drwxrwx--x+ 141 andrew andrew ?`

Comment: check also `ls -ld /home` to see if the http user can get through there

Comment: Linking: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39466/117549

Comment: Linking: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14171/117549

Comment: Linking: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85475/117549

Comment: `group::---` perms on the directory are going to deny access to anyone in the directory's group (aside from the directory's owner).

Comment: @mark-plotnick do I grant the permissions then? `chmod g+rw` doesn't work

Comment: The directory needs to have execute permission, so try `chmod g+rwx`, although giving write access to the http server might not be a good idea, so `g=rx` may be better.

Comment: If you can edit your question to show the exact access various users, groups, and others should have for each directory and file, we can help you adjust your permissions and acls appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

if as `http` user, the following command `newgrp andrew` allows you access the file then the reason will be that a session had not picked up the changes to groups - which usually requires a re-login to take affect.