# Cannot cd to directory even with `rws` group permissions

Tags: permissions, acl

Me and a teammate both have access to a server. We are both in a group that I will call `team`. I created a directory on the server, and with how the system is configured it defaults to `drwxrws---+` with me as the owner and `team` as the group:

```
me@server:/parent_dir$ ls -l
drwxrws---+ 3 me team  4096 Dec 13 20:03 new_dir

me@server:/parent_dir$ getfacl new_dir/
# file: new_dir/
# owner: me
# group: team
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::---
```

My teammate, who I have confirmed is part of `team`, can `cd` to `parent_dir`. From there, when he attempts to `cd` to `new_dir`, he gets the error:

```
-bash: cd: new_dir/: Permission denied
```

Why can't he access the directory?

parent_dir:

```
me@server:/$ ls -l
drwxrws---+   4 root team       4096 Dec 12 21:11 parent_dir

me@server:/$ getfacl parent_dir
# file: parent_dir
# owner: root
# group: team
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:team:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::---
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your team mate actually is in the `team` group? Get them to run the `id` command and look at the groups listed. If they have just now been added to that group, they need to log out and in again.

Comment: @Kusalananda He has been in the group since his account was created a long time ago. I ran `id -Gn` just now to confirm once again, and `team` is listed.

Comment: I also ran `id` without `-Gn` just in case it was any different; it listed `team` as both primary and supplementary.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/390695/5132 is the same, but it has never been satisfactorily answered.

Comment: Please also add the output of `getfacl /parent_dir`. If there is no applicable x permission bit for your teammate, that will prevent access to any file or sub-directory of `parent_dir`.

Comment: @telcoM I have edited in that information, it looks fine to me

Comment: What filesystem type are you using (`mount | grep -F " on $(df -h /parent_dir/new_dir/ | awk 'NR>1{print $NF}') "`)

Comment: @roaima RAID 5 mounted to parent_dir as ext4: `/dev/md126 on /parent_dir type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=112,data=ordered,x-gvfs-show)`